# Convert a list of character vectors into a binary matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix, vector

I am working in R and have a named list of character vectors. Each vector describes the genes present in a biological pathway.

Please see example below:

```
gene_sets = list(pathwayX= c("Gene3"),pathwayY= c("Gene2", "Gene3"),pathwayz= c("Gene1", "Gene2","Gene3"))

> gene_sets
$pathwayX
"Gene3"

$pathwayY
"Gene2" "Gene3"

$pathwayZ
"Gene1" "Gene2" "Gene3"
```

What I want to do is to convert the list into a binary matrix, with genes as columns and pathways as rows. 0 means gene is not present in the pathway and 1 means gene is present.

|  | Gene1 | Gene2 | Gene3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pathwayX | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| pathwayY | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| pathwayZ | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use

```
t(+sapply(gene_sets, "%in%", x = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3")))
```

If you want to dynamically obtain `c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3")`, we can do

```
GeneID <- sort(unique(unlist(gene_sets)))

mat <- t(+sapply(gene_sets, "%in%", x = GeneID))  ## matrix output
colnames(mat) <- GeneID
#         Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
#pathwayX     0     0     1
#pathwayY     0     1     1
#pathwayz     1     1     1

data.frame(mat)  ## data.frame output
```

---

My impression is that genes problem is usually large and sparse. If you have hundreds of thousands of genes and pathways in reality, the following sparse matrix solution is the best option.

```
pathwayID <- names(gene_sets)
n1 <- lengths(gene_sets, use.names = FALSE)  ## number of genes in each pathway
genesVec <- unlist(gene_sets, use.names = FALSE)
GeneID <- sort(unique(genesVec))
i <- rep(1:length(n1), n1)
j <- match(genesVec, GeneID)
Matrix::sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = rep.int(1, length(i)),
                     dimnames = list(pathwayID, GeneID))
#3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#         Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
#pathwayX     .     .     1
#pathwayY     .     1     1
#pathwayz     1     1     1
```

Comment: Tracing `mtabulate` in Quinten's answer, I found the Q&A that motivated this function: [create a data frame of tag frequencies from a list of tag vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9961209/4891738). I have voted up that question. I shall update my answer with a benchmark when I am available.

Answer (score 7):

An idea is to use `table` in combination with `stack` i.e.

```
t(table(stack(gene_sets)))

          values
ind        Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
  pathwayX     0     0     1
  pathwayY     0     1     1
  pathwayz     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` like this:

```r
gene_sets = list(pathwayX= c("gene3"),pathwayY= c("gene2", "gene3"),pathwayz= c("gene1", "gene2","gene3"))

library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(gene_sets)
#>          gene1 gene2 gene3
#> pathwayX     0     0     1
#> pathwayY     0     1     1
#> pathwayz     1     1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Here is a try to solve it with `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
as.data.frame(unlist(gene_sets)) %>% 
  transmute(gene = as.factor(`unlist(gene_sets)`)) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(rowname = str_remove(rowname, "[0-9]")) %>% 
  cbind((model.matrix(~ gene + 0, .) == 1)*1) %>% 
  rename_with(., ~str_replace_all(., "geneGene", "Gene")) %>% 
  group_by(rowname) %>% 
  summarise(across(-gene, ~sum(.)))
```

```
  rowname  Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 pathwayX     0     0     1
2 pathwayY     0     1     1
3 pathwayz     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat concise `tidyverse` way if one were compelled to go down that path.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

map_dfr(gene_sets,
        ~ as_tibble_row(set_names(rep(1L, length(.x)), .x)), .id = "row") %>% 
  relocate(row, order(colnames(.))) %>% 
  mutate(across(-1, replace_na, 0))
```

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  row      Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int>
1 pathwayX     0     0     1
2 pathwayY     0     1     1
3 pathwayz     1     1     1
```